# Constructing Icosahedral Fullerene Graphs

Tags: chemistry, polyhedra, graphs-and-networks

I am interested in constructing graphs of icosahedral fullerenes, following the construction explained in the first few pages of [this article](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/994783/filename/Fullerenes.pdf) ([alternate link](https://www.academia.edu/19051157/Fullerene_Graphs_and_Some_Relevant_Graph_Invariants)).  Mathematica has built-in information about the 60-site graph, $C_{60}$, in `GraphData["TruncatedIcosahedralGraph"]` and `ChemicalData["Fullerene60"]` and information about the 20-site dodecahedron, but there's [a whole zoo of icosahedral fullerenes](http://www.sivakrishna.com/full.html).

First, I construct an underlying hexagonal grid of ions:

```
Li = 10;
Lj = 10;
offset = {-3 - 1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
a1 = {3/2, +Sqrt[3]/2};
a2 = {3/2, -Sqrt[3]/2};
ions = Flatten[Outer[offset + #1 a1 + #2 a2 + #3 (a1 + a2)/3 &,
    Range[-Li, Li], Range[-Lj, Lj], {0, 1}
    (* A/B shift comes last to ensure even/odd sites alternate *)], 2];
```

with a face centered on the origin.  Then I compute the locations of the pentagonal defects:

```
Gi = 1;
Gj = 2;
b1 = {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
b2 = {0, Sqrt[3]};
upRight = {+1, +1} Gj b2 + {+1, -1}*Gi b1;
downRight = {+1, -1} Gi b2 + {+1, +1}*Gj b1 - upRight;
horizontal = upRight + downRight;
pentagonCenters = Flatten[{# horizontal, # horizontal + upRight, # horizontal + 
    2 upRight, # horizontal + downRight} & /@ Range[0, 4], 1] ~Join~
   {5 horizontal, 5 horizontal + upRight};
```

So that you can visually see what I've got,

```
Show[ListPlot[{ions, pentagonCenters}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
              PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-10, 10}}, 
              PlotMarkers -> ({#, Large} & /@ {\[FilledSmallCircle], ★})],
     Graphics[Line /@ (pentagonCenters[[#]] & /@ {
     {1, 3}, {4, 7}, {8, 11}, {12, 15}, {16, 19}, {20, 22}, {1, 4}, {2, 8}, {3, 12},
     {7, 16}, {11, 20}, {15, 21}, {19, 22}, {1, 21}, {2, 22}})]
 ]
```

which, for `Gi = 1; Gj = 2` yields the $C_{60}$ graph [image: Gi=1,Gj=2] where the blue circles are locations of the ions and the stars will be the centers of the pentagonal defects.  The triangles with stars as their vertices are the faces of the icosahedron.

Running again with `Gi=1;Gj=3` yields a 170-ion graph [image: G1=3,Gj=3]

My questions are all aimed at constructing the adjacency matrix for these icosahedral fullerenes.

1. How can I easily "cut out" the ions that aren't inside the black triangles.  Also: the `sites` I generate are definitely too many...

   [**EDIT**]: This can be accomplished with by construction a region:

   ```
    region = Region[Polygon[pentagonCenters[[
        {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 
         21, 20, 17, 16, 13, 12, 9, 8, 5, 4}]]]];
   ```

   and then using `RegionMember`.  I still have to pick `Li` and `Lj` large enough to cover the area of interest.  [**Updated question**]: how can I  just generate the "needed" hexagonal grid to begin with, or just the needed ones plus a little extra, that can then be discarded via `RegionMember`?
2. How can I "stitch up" the sides of the black triangles?  On a hexagonal grid I can detect if two ions are nearest neighbors by seeing if the `Norm` of the difference of their locations differ by 1.  How should I make these identifications in an easy, programmatic way that Mathematica will understand?
3. Bonus:  In an ideal world, I'd know the geometrical locations of all of these ions when the graph is thought of as a polyhedron.  Is there something relatively automatic I can do to get at this information?  [**EDIT**: once I have a `Graph` object I can cast to a `Graph3D` and use `AbsoluteOptions[ graph3D, VertexCoordinates]` to get the locations.]

Note that sometimes ions land exactly on the sides of the black triangles (as in the `Gi=1;Gj=2` case).

Comment: Are you interested in having an understandable algorithm to generate these graphs? Would you be happy with routine that imports the graphs generated by the program described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7010.pdf)?

Comment: Wow, what a find!  In an ideal world I'd have the whole functionality of `Buckygen` in Mathematica!  But as that's obviously a huge task whose benefits I wouldn't reap for a very long time, I would gladly settle for just the icosahedral ones (those where the pentagons are evenly distributed).

Comment: That's a neat paper, @Jason! If you can find time to show how to use it with *Mathematica*, it can be interesting.

Comment: BTW, I presume you're aware of [Goldberg polyhedra](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedra.html)?

Comment: In fact, the paper I'm following above gives a nice visual explanation of Goldberg's original construction, and I called my variables Gi and Gj for Goldberg :)

Answer (score 9):

[Jason B](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b) gave a hint to the tool `buckygen`. This tool is easily downloaded, unpacked and compiled (by running `make` in the unpacked folder).

Assuming that the compiled executable of buckygen is contained in the subfolder buckygen-1.0 of folder Downloads of the current user (and maybe also assuming that you run this on a unixoid OS), you can run buckygen and import the results with the following tiny program. It generates all fullerenes with vertex count between `m` and `n`. Also some but not all   options of buckygen got translated into Mathematica options.

```
ClearAll[getBucky];
getBucky[m_Integer, n_Integer, OptionsPattern[{
    "Dual" -> False,
    "IPROnly" -> False,
    "Statistics" -> False,
    "Verbose" -> True
    }]
  ] := Module[{file, runstring, path, data, time},
  path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Downloads", "buckygen-1.0"}];
  file = FileNameJoin[{path, "FullerDump.g6"}];
  runstring = StringJoin[{"! ", FileNameJoin[{path, "buckygen"}],
     " -s",
     If[OptionValue["Dual"], " -d", ""],
     If[OptionValue["IPROnly"], " -I", ""],
     If[OptionValue["Statistics"], " -v", ""],
     If[! OptionValue["Verbose"], " -q", ""],
     " -S", ToString[m], " ",
     ToString[n], " ", file, " 2>&1 &"}];
  Print[Import[runstring, "Text"]];
  Print["Importing ", file, "..."];
  time = AbsoluteTiming[data = Import[file, "Sparse6"];][[1]];
  Print["Time elapsed for import: ", time, "."];
  Flatten[{data}]
  ]
```

A usage example:

```
data = getBucky[20,20];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[data, 6, 6, {1, 1}, Graphics[]], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

The dual graphs can be obtained with

```
data = getBucky[20, 20, "Dual" -> True];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[data, 6, 6, {1, 1}, Graphics[]], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

The graphs are imported as a list of Mathematica `Graph` objects. (I am using version 11.0.1 and do not know what happens for legacy versions of Mathematica.) For example, you can obtain the `AdjacencyMatrix` of the first fullerene in the list with `AdjacencyMatrix[data[[1]]]`.
Or you can obtain planar embeddings with `PlanarGraph`:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[PlanarGraph /@ data, 6, 6, {1, 1}, Graphics[]], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

If the executable is located somewhere else, adjust the variable `path` in the program to your needs.
If you would like to use other options of `buckygen`, you merely have to adjust the variable `runstring` to your needs.

What's really bugging me is that `Import` for `Sparse6` is very, very slow. Maybe, someone else knows an improvement.

Comment: Very nice! I get compile errors for buckygen on a mac, but the older fullgen works.  The graphs you generated also look pretty neat if you feed them to `Graph3D` or `PlanarGraph`

Comment: @JasonB. I am also on a mac. Sure, I also get several warnings and notes upon compilation. Nonetheless, it works.

Comment: I had a compilation problem because Apple "helpfully" points `gcc` to `clang` (you can check with `gcc --version`, if it points to `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)`, for example, you aren't really using `gcc`).  I also have `gcc-7` installed via `homebrew` and it compiled when I pointed the makefile to `CC = gcc-7`.

Comment: @evanb Anyways, my aim was to show you how to call cammand line tools from within mathematica. That's often much easier than writing a LibraryLink API.

Comment: Indeed.  This is great.  How can I narrow down to the graphs the pentagons are evenly distributed?

Comment: Phew.Operationalize what you mean by "evenly distributed". If you can phrase what it means for either the primal or the dual graph, then you can write a routine for checking if a graph satisfies the "the pentagons are evenly distributed" and use `Select` to pick them out of the huge bowl of fullerene graphs. Giving necessary conditions can also help. E.g. vertices of valence 5 should have same edge distance to their neigboring valence-5-vertices. Look up `VertexDegree` and `FindShortestPath` for that...

Comment: OK, here's what I mean by icosahedral: `IcosahedralQ[g_] := Module[{
   sp = FindShortestPath[g, All, All],
   pent = Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[g], 5]
   },
  And @@ (EqualTo[{{1, 2}, {5, 2}}] /@ 
     Sort /@ Tally /@ (Tally /@ Outer[Length@*sp, pent, pent])[[All, 
         All, 2]])
  ]` but it takes a long time to find the ones higher than n=12 and n=32, simply because the number of graphs grows so quickly.

Comment: Or, put more succinctly, the "evenly distributed" ones are the ones where the pentagons live at the corners of equilateral triangles when the graph is "unfolded" (as in the pictures I provided in the original question).

Comment: Using the `-I` (IPR) and `-V` (requiring a nontrivial group) speeds it up enormously, but it still scales quite badly with n.

Comment: I wonder if you can obtain all the polyhedra you are looking for by the following method: 1. Take an icosahedron with edge lengths equal to $1$. 2. Slice away certain amounts of the corners such that small pentagons of edgle length $1/n$  and hexagons with edge lengths $((n-2)/n, 1/n,(n-2)/n, 1/n,(n-2)/n, 1/n)$ arise. 3. Subdivide the hexagons such that you obtain regular triangles of edge length $1/n$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that procedure doesn't generate all the graphs I want.  If you look at my second figure, you can see that the black triangles are not necessarily tiled hexagons in the "obvious" way.

Comment: Ah, the carbon rings are allowed to bend?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  It kind of blew my mind when I saw those constructions!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher since `buckygen` is GPL3 licensed, I put [a copy on github](https://github.com/evanberkowitz/buckygen/).  I'd like to distribute a Mma notebook with my code that was built on your answer.  However, the default license on SE [is incompatible with GPL3](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/226/can-i-copy-paste-a-snippet-from-stackoverflow-into-my-gnu-gpl-project).  Can you grant a GPL3 license as well?

Comment: @evanb Huh. No problem from my side; I did not invest much creativity anyways. What do I have to do? Does it suffice if I clap my hands thrice and shout "granted"?

Comment: I'm no expert on these matters, but I think such a "verbal" grant should suffice!  I'll make sure to credit you etc.

Comment: Okay ... ... Done.

Comment: No clapping?

Thanks!

Comment: As I said: Done. ;) (I have witnesses, you know...) You're welcome.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher the package is now available at http://github.com/evanberkowitz/buckygen/ .  Thanks again!

Comment: @evanb You should state that as an answer. This will certainly raise a bit more  attention!

Comment: @evanb And many thanks for the credit you gave me. =D