# Generating a Periodic Voronoi Mesh

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mesh, lattices

Consider the following hexagonal mesh, created from `VoronoiMesh`

```
L1 = 4; L2 = 4;
pts = Flatten[Table[{3/2 i ,
      (Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2)
      }, {i, L1 + 4}, {j, L2 + 4}], 1] // N;
mesh0 = VoronoiMesh[pts];
mesh1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh0], 
   With[{a = PropertyValue[{mesh0, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]}, 
    With[{m = 3}, Pick[MeshCells[mesh0, 2], UnitStep[a - m], 0]]]];
mesh = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mesh1], 
  MeshCells[mesh1, {2, "Interior"}]]
```

[image]

I can get the connectivity matrix of such mesh by doing

```
conn = mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]];
lens = PropertyValue[{mesh, 1}, MeshCellMeasure];
$threshold = 0.;
keep = Pick[Range[MeshCellCount[mesh, 1]], 
   UnitStep[Subtract[$threshold, lens]], 0];
conn = conn[[keep]];
adj = Transpose[conn].conn;
arg = Unitize[adj];
ag = (UpperTriangularize[arg, 1] + LowerTriangularize[arg, -1]);
ag // MatrixForm
```

Is it possible to easily change this matrix such that it considers the periodic hexagonal mesh case? I'm aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184792/how-to-build-a-neighbor-table-for-the-hexagonal-lattice), but I am looking for something more general, that could be specifically applied to Voronoi meshes.

More generally, is it possible at all to get the periodic connectivity matrices of meshes like

[image]

which are generated by `VoronoiMesh`?

Ultimately, and this might be reaching too far for now, how hard could it be to fabricate a Voronoi periodic mesh that takes into account the "need to fit" condition, that is, either of the following

[image]

**Edit:** Following Chip Hurst's answer below, I can get the periodicity of the hexagonal mesh by setting

```
Show[Table[
  MeshRegion[
   TransformedRegion[mesh, 
    TranslationTransform[{1.5 L1 i, Sqrt[3] L2 j}]], 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 
     2 -> ColorData[112, 7 i + j + 25]}], {i, 0, 1}, {j, i, 1}]]
```

[image]

This is rather useful, as I can possibly even consider cylindrical periodicity. How would I now get the connectivity matrix from this setting? That is last step I need.

Comment: The question you linked on the heganonal lattice has multiple very detailed answer. Is nothing from there really applicable here? You would want to point out exactly what functionality you seek that was not addressed. Also, Have you seen [Cropping a Voronoi diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31187/27951) and [Making a Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111755/27951)?

Comment: Regarding the linked question, specifically, I would like to avoid using Szabolcs package, since I intend to use this in a CDF, and seems tricky to incorporate IGraph/M in a CDF, in an automated fashion. Regarding the other answer, I can't get `ntab` to yield the matrix that I want, but I'm still trying. Thank you for the other links, I will take a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to periodically tile a Voronoi diagram is to translate your seeds in all directions you'd like to tile, find the Voronoi diagram of this set, then take the cells that correspond to the original data.

Here, I'll tile it in the cardinal directions.

Initial data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
```

Now we augment this data and find a larger Voronoi mesh:

```
pts2 = Flatten[Table[TranslationTransform[{2 i, 2 j}][pts], {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}], 2];

vor = VoronoiMesh[pts2, {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image]

Now pick only the cells the original data lies in:

```
vcells = Catenate[NearestMeshCells[{vor, 2}, #] & /@ pts];

pvor = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[vor], MeshCells[vor, vcells]]
```

[image]

And tile:

```
Show[Table[
  MeshRegion[
    TransformedRegion[pvor, TranslationTransform[{2 i, 2 j}]], 
    MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> ColorData[112, 7 i + j + 25]}
  ], 
  {i, -3, 3}, {j, -3, 3}
]]
```

[image]

---

To get the periodic connectivity matrix, we can start with the connectivity matrix of the larger Voronoi, partition it into a 3x3 collection and sum them.

```
len = Length[pts];

C22 = #.Transpose[#]& @ vor["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]];

cells = Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vor, pts2][[All, 2]];

C22perm = C22[[cells, cells]];

pC22 = SparseArray[Unitize[Total[Partition[Unitize[C22perm], {len, len}], 2]]];
pC22 -= IdentityMatrix[len, SparseArray];

Show[
  pvor,
  AdjacencyGraph[pC22, VertexCoordinates -> pts]
]
```

[image]

Comment: And how do I get the connectivity/adjacency matrix corresponding to the periodic case?

Comment: Also, the last code does not seem to work with my `mesh`.

Comment: I'm getting the error "MeshRegion is not a Graphics primitive or directive"

Comment: See if my edit fixes things.

Comment: I have solved the automatic tiling for the hexagonal mesh, please see the edit. Now I just need a way to get the connectivity matrix.

Comment: Any ideas? I tried to work it out, but can't seem to be able to extract it from your code.

Comment: See my edit. ${}$