# Periodic Voronoi Mesh in a box

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Is it possible to generate a periodic Voronoi Mesh inside a rectangular domain? I would also like to obtain the coordinates of each cell separately so that I can perform further operations on each cell.

Edit: The following code as mentioned in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220386/generating-a-periodic-voronoi-mesh?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems to work fine to generate a periodic pattern.

```
(* Initial Data *)
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
(* Augment data and find the larger Voronoi Mesh *)

pts2 = Flatten[
   Table[TranslationTransform[{2 i, 2 j}][pts], {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 
     1}], 2];
vor1 = VoronoiMesh[pts2, {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
vor2 = VoronoiMesh[pts2, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
coord = MeshCoordinates[vor2];
Show[vor2, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[coord]}]]
```

[image]
[image]

Getting all the coordinates is easily done with MeshCoordinates. However, getting the group of coordinates separately for each cell is what I am looking for.

Comment: The expensive way is to periodically pad your data, compute the usual Voronoi diagram, and crop back.

Comment: How about the second part of the question? How do I go about obtaining the coordinates of each cell separately?Eventually, I would like to perform a self-similar contraction of each cell so as to create parallel gaps between each cell. I guess if I have coordinates of each cell, perform the self-similar transformation would be easy.

Comment: That depends. Are you fine with a cell near a corner of the rectangular domain being split into four different polygons? Also, have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220386) already?

Comment: Yes, the splitting should be fine. I have seen the post, the first part of the question seems to work but extracting the coordinates separately for each cell is where I am stuck at.

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the post. Thanks!

Comment: `MeshPrimitives` maybe?

Comment: `MeshPrimitives[vor2,2]` does give me polygon objects but how I do then find the coordinates from there on?